# How to use check duplicate record in beanshell and the database is using Heidi SQL

Tags: java, sql, validation, duplicates, beanshell

I have face some issue for the requirement that stated that the user can only order one order on that day. I am using beanshell and my database is HeidiSQL. How can I scan the database and find is there any duplication of the record? such as i thinking of using date and UserID to check the duplication in the record. What can I use? Is there any sample code or solution about this?

Comment: Can you share the table structure and DBMS you are using?

Comment: c_orderid  | c_userid | c_menudate | c_category | c_menudescription | c_pickuppoint

Comment: What is that mean DBMS?

Comment: "my database is HeidiSQL".  HeidiSQL is the tool you use to connect to the database, it isn't the database itself.  The database is likely to be either MariaDB or MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

HeidiSQL is a GUI used to interface to a database.  It is not a database.  The most common databases are MySQL and Postgres, and fortunately, you can use the same syntax in both datases:

```
select c_userid, date(c_menudate), count(*) as cnt
from t
group by c_userid, date(c_menudate)
having count(*) >= 2;
```

This assumes that `c_menudate` is the date/time of the order.  If it does not have a time component, then you don't need the `date()` function.